# "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties." in Adobe Animate

Tags: flash, css-animations, adobe, cc, adobe-animate

i am creating a game rn, and i have popup feature on my game,i make 2 popup for my game, but when i aplly the code for the second popup, it doesn't work, can you help me by seeing my code, thank you. there's an error appeared.

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at TugasMMIFIX_fla::MainTimeline/addPopup_2()
at TugasMMIFIX_fla::MainTimeline/popupBaju()
```

And this is my code (including the first popup code):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var popup = new popupRumahMC;
var isPopup = false;

function addPopup(str=""):void{
 popup = new popupRumahMC;
 popup.closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closePopup);
 popup.x = 640;
 popup.y = 360;
 addChild(popup);
 isPopup = true;
}

function removePopup():void{
 popup.closeBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closePopup);
 removeChild(popup);
 isPopup = false;
}

function closePopup(e:MouseEvent):void{
 removePopup();
}

rumahBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,popuprumah)
function popuprumah(e:MouseEvent){
addPopup(); 
}

//popup 2//

var popup_2 = new popupBajuMC;
var isPopup_2 = false;

function addPopup_2(str=""):void{
 popup_2 = new popupBajuMC;
 popup_2.copycloseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closePopup_2);
 popup_2.x = 643;
 popup_2.y = 360;
 addChild(popup_2);
 isPopup_2 = true;
}

function removePopup_2():void{
 popup_2.copycloseBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closePopup_2);
 removeChild(popup_2);
 isPopup_2 = false;
}

function closePopup_2(e:MouseEvent):void{
 removePopup_2();
}

bajuBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,popupBaju)
function popupBaju(e:MouseEvent){
addPopup_2();   
}
```

I'm trying to fix that error, and unfortunately, it fails. I have double-checked it. What do you think is the problem with this code?

Comment: _"I'm trying to fix that error"_ Try using **trace** to check what the compiler sees. What happens if, after `popup_2 = new popupBajuMC;` you add the line `trace( "popup is : " + popup_2);`? Also trace to check if **copycloseBtn** is not null/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Adobe Animate, but please allow me to share my experience.

I found nothing wrong in your code, the first popup and the second popup code are similar.
I suggest that you re-checking the instance name and object/symbol properties. But if you already did that then I think it's not the code error, but more like the same problem I got recently.

---

#### My Solution

Try put your button (insert keyframe) from the first frame. You can hide it (alpha 0% or 0% width/height) or put it outside the frame if you didn't use it.
Before: [Timeline Before Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2gv2.png)
After: [Timeline After Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLvyE.png)
Button Code: [Button Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJLM3.png) (I didn't change this)
This do the trick for me.

#### Update

Finally, find a simple solution for me:
> Fixed by **Disabling the "Use Advanced Layer"** at Document Setting.
[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD6Uj.png)
Note: By disabling it you can't use some features (see the popup message).

---

Hope this helps.